# Postman Pre-request script

Tags: javascript, postman

I am trying to hit a particular API, which actually send the OTP to customers, their is not Rate Limiter is their on this API, So I am trying to write a pre-request script that will run multiple times, in which I pass the two numbers in the code given below, but main problem is it is not working for the two numbers, it takes only one number which is I pass in the body of the postman which is in JSON format, it doesn't go in the script, please help me to solving this

**Postman Request Type :** POST

**API URL :** http:// (API URL)

**Body :**

```
{"mobile_number":"94XXXXXXXX","template":"login","countryCode":"91"}
```

**Pre-request Script:**

```
var mobiles = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("mobiles");

if (!mobiles)
  {
    mobiles =["88XXXXXXXX","80XXXXXXXX"];  
  }

var currentMobile = mobiles.shift();
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("mobile", currentMobile);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("mobiles", mobiles);
```

**Tests:**

```
var mobiles = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("mobiles");

if (mobiles && mobiles.lenght > 0)
  {
    postman.setNextRequest("API URL");  
  }
  else
  {
      postman.setNextRequest("null");
  }
```

P.S : I am not sharing the API url here, and the mobile number . Sorry for that

Comment: @sivcan-singh please help

Comment: Can you share the `body` of the request in which you're using the variables?

Comment: Also, are you saying that you're passing the mobile numbers in the body of the request and they're not available in the pre-request script?